# Urdu not typed after selecting Urdu as input method

Tags: fonts

I have selected Urdu as input source from settings and when I write something in text editor, roman font writes except of Urdu font.

I have slide that written in Urdu and Arabic font and have installed *Jameel Noori Nastaleeq , fonts-noto Pak Nastaleeq (Beta Release).ttf, Fajer Noori Nastalique 15-12-2006.ttf and asunaskh.ttf* fonts but slide font does not show clearly.

The text is broken and unreadable and I have uploaded an image:

[image]

At the top right of the image, the input language is Urdu but when I write something it gets typed in English.

Kindly give some suggestion?

Comment: Can you please install the `fonts-nafees` package from the Ubuntu archive and let us know if it makes a difference.